# Error in file... which I already deleted - how can I fix this?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I installed an extension which causes some troubles so I decided to load a backup. I got an error message `Base table or view already exists:1050 Table 'desktopnotification' already exists`, so I just deleted the database since it was unimportant. But I still get the error massage. What can I do now?

This is how the trace look like:

```
Trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.2')
#3 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache and re-index?

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Always clear browser cache, magento cache -> var/logs/cache , re-index and enter the URL of the admin panel again in the browser. It should work now!

Comment: Glad to help, I have made my comment into an answer. Please kindly accept it if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you make any major changes to your shop's Magento extensions, be sure to clear the cache, re-index, and re-compile (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you still want this module installed or not?
Uninstalling some modules is not easy in magento 1.x and usually there is an uninstallation quide with it.

You state that you laded a backup. A backup of what and how?

In anyway your error happens because a module (let's call it "MyModule"), has an installation script that causes a db table to be created. The table's name is "[desktopnotification]".

Apparently when you loaded the backup, the entry "MyModule_setup" in "core_resource" table of your database was deleted, but the table "desktopnotification" was not.

You have 5 choices

1. Disable the module by stating `<active>false</active>` in /app/etc/modules/MyVendor_MyModule.xml
2. Delete the module either by manually deleting all files related to it or by uninstalling it drom Magento Connect manager
3. Delete the table [desktopnotification]. Keep in mind that ot will deleted all related data. Never a good idea
4. Goto to app/code/[local|community]/MyVendor/MyModule/sql/.../blablabla.php

Find `CREATE TABLE {[desktopnotification]} (`

And replace it with`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {[desktopnotification]} (`

5. Contact the Module Vendor for instructions

I would go with (5)